# For loop in R Explanation

Tags: r, for-loop

Could someone explain this line of coding for me in layman's term? The line is

```
for(i in 1: length(batch_list))
```

I understand what a for loop is I think.

Comment: Did my answer help you understanding what it is? There is no way to simplify it more. Feel free to tick it as the correct answer to help others understanding too. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i in 1: length(batch_list)) {   #The counter declaration
  #then do something for each iteration
  print(i)
  #....
} #And finish the enviroment.
```

For a variable `i` the loop will do something in the range (till the `length` reached) of `1` and the end of your list (here. `batch_list`). Let's say your list is `10` long. It will printing out every step (iteration) till it reached `10`. And finish the enviroment when the range is reached and the loop finished.

It also could be written with `for(i in 1: 10)` instead.

Same result for both:

```
## [1] 1
## [1] 2
## [1] 3
## [1] 4
## [1] 5
## [1] 6
## [1] 7
## [1] 8
## [1] 9
## [1] 10
```